# +rep notification showing incorrect title for example

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation, notifications

I just got a "+5 rep" notification for an upvote to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/713/using-dom#t=201607270713565433553) example.

The notification looks like this:

[image]

While the title of the example is "**Using DOM**":

[image]

Apparently, a older revision is used to get the title, to show in the notification.

Comment: Noticed that too and wondered.

Comment: Yep, you're right; the vote for #713 was `2016-07-27 07:13:46.607` (GMT); the title has been "Using DOM" since 8:30 on the 25th... investigating; edit: ah, the problem is the transfer from the "single site" data to the "entire network" data (that we use for things like rep-history messages); the title change was not correctly updates in the "entire network" data

Comment: @MarcGravell: Hiccup or actual bug? :P I've also found another (error page) [bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329766/error-page-when-opening-specific-proposed-change), a moment ago.

Comment: @Cerbrus bug, I think; working on it...

Comment: Actually, now I look at it some more, all notifications are using older titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much head-scratching, it turns out this was due to an oversight during migration from "beta"; only topics and examples that existed *during the isolated beta* are affected. The title used for notifications will be updated automatically when any edit is made to the existing posts; I will, however, see whether we can do a bulk backfill to fix the impacted data (not all that many of them).

This was subtle and nuanced and hard to reproduce - very much thanks for reporting it.

Comment: You're welcome :D Thanks for the response!