# Error page when opening specific proposed change

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals, error-message

I'm in the "[Proposed changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript?tab=proposedchanges)" tab of the JavaScript topic, where I try to open [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/13074):

[image]

It redirects to the following error page:

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/proposed/changes/13074

Comment: I get this too, for this change and occasional others.  It seems highly intermittent and I can't identify a common theme between which propsed changes trigger this behaviour.

Comment: I had this too. Mine was when I had moved 2 examples to the same topic. I got the error until the first proposed change was approved...

Comment: same here, for [Proposed Change 61925](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/61925)

Comment: Same here for @MSalters 's change http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/44522

Comment: It happens also for me when moving examples. (I deleted my proposal afterward to avoid to pollute with invalid proposal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this got fixed some time since July. :)

Probably somewhere around when we switched to /review for Documentation changes.