# Notification from Documentation results in an error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Today I got two notifications from Documentation, but they both lead to `http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/s/td/pc/396/129592` with random cat or person on computer pictures.

I say anything that gets me moar cat pics cannot possibly be filed as a bug - but just posting this here FYI.

Comment: This can happen if the notifications are for moves. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329766/215552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that [`https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/td/pc/396/129592`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/td/pc/396/129592) link is what we call a "short link", one that ultimately results in a redirect to a canonical url.

In this case, the url is for a proposed change, one that is now retracted by the author.  The redirect code wasn't loading retracted changes, which resulted in a null reference exception and error page.

This has now been fixed.